# chicago boss Reference sequence/collection elements from a view

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I am a new comer to CB and I'm working on a project in which I need to pass a list of the previous 12 months from today's date to the view, in the fashion of Year,Month, so that the view writes something as follows for each.

```
<div class="date">
      <h4>2103</h4>
      <div<JAN</div>
 </div>
```

I haven't been able to figure out a variable schema in order to properly reference the elements on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered [elsewhere](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/chicagoboss/9441gAg0PKI%22elsewhere%22), so I am filling in for reference.

A list of lists do the job:

On Controller:

```
Dates = [ [{year, "2013"}, {month, "JAN"}], [{year, "2013"}, {month, "FEB"}] ],
```

and pass the var to the template: `{dates, Dates}`

On view:

```
{% for date in dates %}
    Year: {{ date.year }}<br>
    Month: {{ date.month }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```